# What are the measures to take if an answer is copied from other developer forums

Tags: discussion

I want to know what are the measures to take if anyone copied an answer from other developer forums and replied in stack exchange as there answer.Because few days back one person with huge reputation has just blindly copied the answer from other developer forums and replied for a question with out sharing any link because it means he duplicates it.

So,For reference i post a comment and share the link where he copied the answer But, i didn't down vote the answer.In a couple of minutes he modified his answer with out comments.So,then lot of users commented on me after the see the updated answer.They don't know the answer before modified and they are suggesting to me how to behave in formus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good to include references in answers, most definitely to official resources. But imo it is not a definite must if you'd only reference elsewhere to the exact same contant. It however is definitely preferred to at the very least duplicate the relevant bits from external sources so that the actual answer is contained in the answer here on salesforce.stackexchange.

Commenting references or adding them to answers by edit are both fine.